# Subclass is not recognized from generic super class

Tags: java, generics

Im trying to only allow specific classes to be used by the interact method. The code does not compile and does not recognize an underlying class to be part of the superclass.

**Im using the following structure:**

- abstract class **Interactable**
- abstract class **Building** extends Interactable
- abstract class **ContainerBuilding** extends Building
- class **Cutter** extends ContainerBuidling

Why does the code below not compile? Cutter.class is not recognized as a building class.

```
  public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        ActionTest.<Building>interact ( Cutter.class );
    }

    public static <T extends Interactable> void interact ( Class<T> interactableClass ) {
        // do something
    }
```

Does also not compile:

```
   public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        ActionTest.interact ( Cutter.class );
    }

    public static void interact ( Class<Interactable> interactableClass ) {
        // do something
    }
```

Comment: You would need to change the signature of the method to accept a `Class<? extends Interactable>`. Can you change the signature of `interact`?

Comment: Yes that works. What is the difference between T and ?.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, change the type of `interactableClass` to `Class<? extends T>`:

```
public static <T extends Interactable> void interact ( Class<? extends T> interactableClass )
```

That's because generics in Java are invariant, which means you cannot pass anything other than `Class<Building>` when you call that method as `<Building>interact(...)` if the parameter is declared as `Class<T>`.